# event handler not working asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

So i was trying to make a simple event handler in asp.net but it doesnt seem to work can someone tell me what am i doing wrong ? ty
so what im doing is a login error handler if the user inserts the wrong user or pass it calls this event

```
       AddHandler UserFailed(Err.Number), AddressOf userError


     Public Event UserFailed(ByVal ErroNo As Integer)


        MsgBox("The user does not exists" & vbCrLf & "or the password is wrong" _
               & vbCrLf & vbCrLf _
               & "Error: " & errorNo)

    End Sub
```

and i declared the error as
`Private Sub userError(ByVal errorNo As Integer) Handles curUser.UserFailed`
what i mean from not working is when i add the "Err.Number" inside the

```
AddHandler UserFailed(Err.Number), AddressOf userError it says the following "addhandler or remove handler statement event operant must be a dot qualified expression or simple name" sry im noob xD
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove `(Err.Number)` from your `AddHandler` as the error tells you to do.

The value is passed when you raise the event (show below), not when you add the handler.

`RaiseEvent UserFailed(Err.Number)`